# not able scrape the element which contain the a text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

could someone assist me with an issue, I am trying to scrape the the dish name with a tag **MUST TRY** but I don't know why it is printing the list of all dishes

**CODE :**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/pune/bedekar-tea-stall-sadashiv-peth/order")
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")  # get the screen height of the web
i = 1
count = 0
scroll_pause_time = 1

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")

#block of code where i am struggling with

dish_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'sc-1s0saks-11 cYGeYt']")
for items in dish_divs:
    if items.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'MUST TRY')]"):

        name = items.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h4.sc-1s0saks-15.iSmBPS')
        print(name.text)
    else:
        continue
driver.close()
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['Misal Slice', 'Shev Chivda', 'Kharvas [Sugar]', 'Extra Rassa [1 Vati]', 'Taak', 'Extra Slice', 'Misal Slice', 'Kharvas [Jaggery]', 'Solkadhi', 'Kokam', 'Nimboo Sharbat', 'Shev Chivda', 'Batata Chivda', 'Misal Slice', 'Extra Kanda [1 Vati]', 'Extra Slice', 'Extra Rassa [1 Vati]', 'Coffee Kharvas', 'Rose Kharvas', 'Shengdana Ladoo', 'Chirota', 'Kharvas [Sugar]', 'Kharvas [Jaggery]', 'Chocolate Fudge', 'Taak', 'Kokam', 'Flavored Milk', 'Nimboo Sharbat', 'Solkadhi', 'Dahi']
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :**
the list of dishes with musttry tag like in image below. My script is getting all the names not the selected ones

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this xpath :

```
//div[text()='MUST TRY']/../../../h4
```

and use in code like this :

```
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='MUST TRY']/../../../h4"):
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: You can write this code, after `#block of code where i am struggling with` line in your code.

Comment: your also working fine buddy @cruisepandey  can you tell me resources from where i could become professional web scraper ,it will be a great help bcz i don't have any senior

Comment: You need to practice a lot, and try to learn xpath, css locators, https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: and what about learning all scraping libs interchangeably within a project ,like in depth knowledge and their uses

Comment: See there are tons of libs, you have to identify which one will be good for the project that you've assigned, Selenium is bit slow, so some folks prefer BS4, or request module, but for some UI visibility is more important so they choose Selenium, helium. Some do not want to use selenium cause they do not like switching to iframes, windows, also you have to write large program in Selenium, but in helium they are very short. Even I am learning web scrapping everyday. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```py
dish_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'sc-1s0saks-11 cYGeYt']")
for items in dish_divs:
    if items.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'MUST TRY')]"):

        name = items.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h4.sc-1s0saks-15.iSmBPS')
        print(name.text)
    else:
        continue
```

You can use

```py
dish_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-1s0saks-1 dpXgPd"]/preceding-sibling::h4')
for items in dish_divs:
    print(items.text)
```

This will make your code more readable and easy to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Here `items.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'MUST TRY')]")` you're using absolute XPath (search all elements from the `root`). In fact you need **relative** XPath (search only in the current element):

```
items.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[contains(text(),'MUST TRY')]")
```

You can get same result using a single XPath:

```
//div[div/div[@type="tag"][.="MUST TRY"]]/preceding-sibling::h4[1]/text()
```

Also I don't recommend you to parse HTML using Selenium. It's really slow for this. I recommend to use lxml or beautifulsoup.

You can use above XPath like this:

```
from lxml import html

....
content = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(content)

titles = tree.xpath('//div[div/div[@type="tag"][.="MUST TRY"]]/preceding-sibling::h4[1]/text()')
```

Comment: where should i put this     ** //div[div/div[@type="tag"][.="MUST TRY"]]/preceding-sibling::h4[1]/text()** in if condition?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[div/div[@type="tag"][.="MUST TRY"]]/preceding-sibling::h4[1]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)  **error**